# C / Linux: setgid leaves root in list of groups

Tags: c, linux

I'm dropping root privileges with `setregid(real_gid, effective_gid)`. Both are set to 1000, but when I'm running id command there's root in group list! How do I remove that?

Comment: This is a legitimate question about how to program with group lists; it is not off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `root` is one of the auxilliary groups, you'll need to use [`getgroups()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getgroups.html) and `setgroups()` to adjust the auxilliary groups list - removing `root` (0) from that list.  Note that POSIX specifies `getgroups()` but does not specify `setgroups()`.

You could probably use code similar to this:

```
enum { MAX_AUX_GROUPS = 16 };  // Reasonable number
enum { ROOT_GROUP     = 0  };  // Platform specific

gid_t aux_groups[MAX_AUX_GROUPS];
int ngroups = getgroups(MAX_AUX_GROUPS, aux_groups);
if (ngroups > 0)
{
    int dst = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ngroups; i++)
    {
        if (aux_groups[i] != ROOT_GROUP)
            aux_groups[dst++] = aux_groups[i];
    }
    ngroups = dst;
}
if (ngroups > 0)
{
    if (setgroups(ngroups, aux_groups) != 0)
        ...report error...
}
```

Note that the `root` group is 0 on Linux, but the name of group 0 is not always `root` (e.g. it is `system` on AIX and `wheel` on MacOS X) and not all systems have a group `root` (neither AIX nor MacOS X, again).  Note too that the kernel does not grant any special privileges to group 0 by virtue of it being group 0 (whereas it does grant special privileges to user 0).

You can generalize the code by looking up the group(s) you want to omit.  POSIX provides an NGROUPS_MAX too; you could use that in place of MAX_AUX_GROUPS.  The standard page also suggests:

```
long ngroups_max = sysconf(_SC_NGROUPS_MAX) + 1;
gid_t *group = (gid_t *)malloc(ngroups_max *sizeof(gid_t));
```

Comment: If you're dropping root you almost surely want to get rid of **all** root's supplemental groups, not just 0. I would skip the `getgroups` and just pass an empty list to `setgroups`. Or if you want to setup the target user's supplemental groups from the group file, there is a (nonstandard but traditionally available) `initgroups` function which will do exactly that.

Comment: @R..: good points. I might argue that if an ordinary user belongs to, say, 6 groups and the setuid/setgid program wants to drop elevated privileges, it should leave the user's 6 groups alone. Granted, the user's group list shouldn't include 'root' in the first place. So, the situation is a little unclear. You can use `setgroups()` with either 0 or with 1 group (the effective group ID; it is implementation defined whether  `getgroups()` returns the effective group ID). The `initgroups()` function takes a user name and a group ID and ensures that the group list is set correctly.

Comment: I think the situation OP is working with is not a suid-root program dropping its suid privileges, but rather a daemon started as root that wants to become an unprivileged user.

Comment: @R..: hmmm, well, it could be either scenario; the question simply doesn't say.  For the daemon scenario, `initgroups()` is usually a better and simpler choice (when `initgroups()` is available; when it isn't, simulating it might well be better than inventing a new interface).  All of which goes to show that specifying the problem accurately helps get better answers.

Comment: If it were just a suid-root program, the supplementary groups list would be unchanged from the group list of the calling user. That's why I believe OP is starting from full root and trying to drop privs.